# codigo php funciona en localhost pero no en la web

Tags: php, mysqli, servidor

tengo un inconveniente al momento de subir mi sitio web, si ejecuto en el servidor local funciona correctamente, pero al momento de subirlo al servidor web me genera error. la query a la bd esta bien.
esta es mi conexion

```
class Conexion extends mysqli{

private $DB_HOST = 'localhost:3306';
private $DB_USER = 'USUARIO';
private $DB_PASS = 'PASSWORD';
private $DB_NAME = 'DBMILAN';

public function __construct(){
    parent:: __construct($this->DB_HOST, $this->DB_USER, $this->DB_PASS, $this->DB_NAME);

    $this->set_charset('utf-8');

    $this->connect_errno ? die('Error en la conexion'. mysqli_connect_errno()) : $m = 'Conectado';
}
```

}

clase consulta

```
  include_once 'class.conexion.php';
    class Consultas  extends Conexion{
    public function selectAssoc($sql){
    if ($result = $this->query($sql)){
      $array = array();
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array[] = $row;
      }
      return $array;
    }else{
      return $array;
    }
    $result->free();
    $this.close();
  }
}
```

y el formulario en el cual quiero visualizar mis productos

```
<TABLE>...
$consultas= new Consultas();
        $sql = "select * from productos";
        $res = $consultas->selectAssoc($sql);
        foreach ($res as $row) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>'.$row["idProducto"].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row["unidadMedida"].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row["nombre"].'</td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ...</TABLE>
```

Este error me muestra

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/tradingc/insaras.trading727.com/facturacion/producto.php on line 173
```

que hace ref. a "foreach ($res as $row) {"

Comment: El select tal cual como está funciona usando el phpmyadmin del hosting?

Comment: esta linea retornada true asi no devuelva nada porque se ejecuto correctamente `if ($result = $this->query($sql)){ //code }` debes hacer esto  if($result->num_rows > 0){ // tu codigo} esto evaluara que por lo menos tenga 1 resultado! si no retornas false no un array vacio y evaluas  `if($res){//code}` tambien el `$result->free();` jamas se ejecuta ya que hay 2 return antes esto debe ir despues del while

Comment: Hay algunas incoherencias en tu código, como dice @Bryro, el `free()` no se ejecutará nunca porque está después del `return`, y aquí hay un error de sintaxis: `$this.close();` Tampoco estableces ningún control sobre el código para verificar si: 1. Hay conexión; 2. La consulta es correcta (no error de sintaxis, no nomnres de tablas o columnas inexistentes); 3. La consulta trajo datos. En todos esos casos en vez de un array en blanco, puedes devolver un array con una clave `error` y un mensaje indicando lo que ha ocurrido.

Comment: Tofo ese código funciona bien en mi servidor local. No modifique nada del código. Esta tal cual

Comment: @A.Cedano Cedano el $this.close(); y $result->free() solo era para liberar memoria, voy a corregirlo, pero si aun quito eso en mi localhost funciona, hare un procedimiento para comprobar la conexion a la bd, como digo en el localhost funciona.

Comment: Aunque funcione, el código no es coherente y deja de controlar muchas cosas, como posibles errores. Dado que estás en remoto, puede por ejemplo que no se esté conectado porque la contraseña es otra. En un código que controle los tres puntos que te puse más arriba sabrías lo que ocurre, pero aquí no lo sabes porque a tu código le faltan precisamente esos controles. En cuanto a lo que digo del `close` lo que quiero que entiendas es que nada de lo que hay después de `return` se ejecuta en ningún código. Eso está mal puesto ahí, aunque no de error.

Comment: gracias @A.Cedano. ya me esta funcionando, el problema era en el include, copie el archivo al directorio raiz y ya esta, ahora tengo dos archivos de conexion, hare los arreglos me que indicaste

Comment: me puede apoyar con cerrar esta pregunta, soy novato en stackoverflos @A.Cedano

Comment: Si quieres  la puedes `eliminar`, usando las opciones que aparecen al pie de la pregunta, a la izquierda de tu nombre. OJO, las preguntas que pueden ser útiles a otros no se eliminan, se guardan con la(s) respuesta(s) para que sirvan a otros usuarios que en un futuro puedan tener un problema similar.